# Get all images and css using Web Request (Network - Google Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I want to get the same results that Google Chrome get on his Network functionality [Network Google Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/network.html). I found [this](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/webRequest.html), but i'm not sure if it works and how to use it. Basically i want to use that information to made a google chrome extension.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [chrome.devtools.network API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/beta/devtools.network.html) would be better suited for your use.

Comment: I just found out that it is. Thanks for your answer.